# Solve the equation: $\frac{x^2 - 2x + 3}{\lbrace x\rbrace} + \frac{2023}{2}{\lbrace x\rbrace} = 2\lfloor x \rfloor + 88$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

**Problem**

Solve the equation

$\frac{x^2 - 2x + 3}{\lbrace x\rbrace} + \frac{2023}{2}{\lbrace x\rbrace} = 2\lfloor x \rfloor + 88$,

where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\{x\}$ are the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ and the fractional part of $x$, respectively.

- This problem is from the Team Round of a local high school math competition that has ended recently

**My work so far**

$x$ can not be an integer because $\lbrace x\rbrace = 0$ will be dividing by zero.
Therefore, $x$ is not an integer.

We can express $x$ as $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lbrace x\rbrace$. Lets say $\lfloor x \rfloor = a$, and $\lbrace x\rbrace = b$.

So $x = a + b.$

We have:

$((a+b)^2 - 2(a+b) + 3) + \frac{2023}{2} b^2 = 2ab + 88b$

which turns into:

$2a^2 + 2025b^2 - 4a -180b + 6 = 0$

(Hopefully I did my math correctly)

I am not too sure what to do from here on. Am I going in the right direction? Am I supposed to solve this equation? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? It would be a shame to see a question like this downvoted due to lack of effort.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I will edit my post and add some things that I have tried :)

Comment: @NinadMunshi i added some of my work! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track. Take your last equation and complete the square

$$2\Bigr(\lfloor x\rfloor-1\Bigr)^2 + \Bigr(45\{x\}-2\Bigr)^2 = 0$$

The only way the sum of two nonnegative terms is $0$ is if they were both $0$ individually. This leaves us with the answer

$$\begin{cases}\lfloor x\rfloor = 1 \\ \{x\} = \frac{2}{45}\end{cases} \implies \boxed{x = \frac{47}{45}}$$